# Functions are not serialized using "serialijse" module of nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, serialization

Normal JSON is working fine for me like
{id:1,"name"="test"}
is serialised properly but on define function in JSON object is not being serialized properly.

**Below is the code**

```js
  var s = require("serialijse")
  var o = {"b":function (){alert('hello world');}}
  var str = s.serialize(o);
  console.log(str);
```

**Error shown**

```js
/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/serialijse/lib/serialijse.js:116
                    throw new Error("invalid typeof " + typeof object + " " + JSON.stringify(object, null, " "));
                    ^

Error: invalid typeof function undefined
    at _serialize (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/serialijse/lib/serialijse.js:116:27)
    at _serialize_object (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/serialijse/lib/serialijse.js:89:38)
    at _serialize (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/serialijse/lib/serialijse.js:113:21)
    at Object.serialize (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/serialijse/lib/serialijse.js:122:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/acid/node_js/newtest/serial.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

What can be the possible way to rectify this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize functions with `serialijse`. See the docs:

> serialijse is an simple persistence framework for JavaScript that overcomes two main limitation of JSON persistence:
>
> 1. serialijse deals well with cyclic objects.
> 2. serialijse preserve object class upon deserialization.

It doesn't say anywhere that it can serialize functions.

As simple test like:

```
serialijse.serialize(()=>{});
```

or:

```
serialijse.serialize({x: ()=>{}});
```

can demonstrate that it doesn't. It wouldn't even make much sense to serialize functions in JavaScript because functions create lexical closures and you wouldn't have access to the same lexical scope that the original function has. For example consider this:

```
let x;
// some more code
let f = a => x += a;
```

How would you serialize that function? Or a bigger problem - how would you deserialize it?

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is serializing the date function so why not serialized own functions ? like this   var s = require("serialijse")
  var o = {"b":Date()}    and serialized form is : [[{"c":"Object","d":{"b":"Mon Mar 13 2017 16:04:52 GMT+0530 (IST)"}}],{"o":0}]